# ¿Por qué recibo el error 'CharField', AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FIXED_NCHAR' en Django con Oracle 11g?

Tags: python, django, oracle, oracle-11g, python-2.x

Tengo el siguiente problema configurando Django. Con:

- Oracle XE 11G
- Python 2.7
- Django 1.11
- cx_Oracle 5.1.3

Archivo `settings.py`:

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
'NAME': 'xe',
'USER': 'pr',
'PASSWORD': 'pr',
'HOST':'localhost',
'PORT':'1521',
```

Al ejecutar el comando `migrate`, sale este error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "manage.py", line 22, in
>   execute_from_command_line(sys.argv) File
>   "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 363, in execute_from_command_line utility.execute() File
>   "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 337, in execute django.setup() File
>   "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django__init__.py", line 27, in setup
>   apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS) File
>   "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in
>   populate app_config.import_models() File
>   "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in
>   import_models self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
>   File "c:\python27\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
>   import(name) File
>   "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4,
>   in from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser,
>   BaseUserManager File
>   "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line
>   52, in class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model): File
>   "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 124, in
>   new new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label)) File
>   "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 330, in
>   add_to_class value.contribute_to_class(cls, name) File
>   "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 214,
>   in contribute_to_class self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table,
>   connection.ops.max_name_length()) File
>   "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db__init__.py", line 33, in
>   getattr return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item) File
>   "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 211, in
>   getitem backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE']) File
>   "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 115, in
>   load_backend return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name) File
>   "c:\python27\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
>   import(name) File
>   "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\base.py",
>   line 60, in from .introspection import DatabaseIntrospection # NOQA
>   isort:skip File
>   "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\introspection.py",
>   line 12, in class DatabaseIntrospection(BaseDatabaseIntrospection):
>   File
>   "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\introspection.py",
>   line 19, in DatabaseIntrospection

---

```
 cx_Oracle.FIXED_NCHAR: 'CharField', AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FIXED_NCHAR'
```

Comment: no existe el atributo `FIXED_NCHAR` verifica en tu modelo el atributo mencionado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo solucione, el problema era de las versiones django 1.11 no es compatible con cx_Oracle 5.1.3, toco instalar django 1.1.3